# Is it possible to reload a view when a tab bar item is pressed?

Tags: iphone, tabbar

It doesn't seem like each time a view is presented via the tab bar, that the `viewDidAppear` method gets called. I've searched as much as I could on this issue, but haven't really found a definitive answer.

Are there any suggestions or workarounds to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` to function properly in a tab bar controller, you'll want to be sure to call those methods when you display the tab bar controller itself.  That is, if you are creating your `UITabBarController` programmatically, be sure to call those methods:

```
UITabBarController *myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[myTabBarController setViewControllers:myViewControllerArray];
[myTabBarController viewWillAppear:NO];
[[self view] addSubview:[myTabBarController view]];
[myTabBarController viewDidAppear:NO];
```

If your tab bar controller is being created in a NIB file, this doesn't apply - and in that case I'm not sure why your `viewDidAppear` method would not be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.